# display list in wpf datagrid control

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How to display a sharepoint list(having 3 columns) in WPF datagrid control.

please provide reply with a sample..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

use the SharePoint client object model.

A great sample source is this [one](http://www.google.fr/search?q=sharepoint+client+object+model+wpf+sample)